# How do I use Pushwoosh with Phonegap / Cordova?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, pushwoosh

I build apps for Android and Apple using Cordova / Phonegap.  I am trying to add push messaging using Pushwoosh, but I have been very unsuccessful.

I have followed their instructions here: http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/cordova-phonegap

For Android, I add the plugin via command line, and then update the config.xml as directed. I copy their javascript code and put that in an index.js file and then link to that from the homepage of my app.  I also include the PushwooshAndroid.js and I update the code with my GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID and PUSHWOOSH_APP_ID.

That is where their documentation ends, and so I do not do anything from there.  No device is registered in the Pushwoosh dashboard after I install the app on my device.

Has anyone had success with this?

I am using Eclipse with Cordova 3.6.3

Comment: What is the type of your testing device, @user2165652?

Comment: I am testing on an LG G3.

Comment: Does your device have Google Play services (can judged by Google Play app existence) installed? Any devices without Google Play services installed will never respond to push notifications that are sent from GCM.

Comment: Yes, Google Play services is installed.  I have contacted psuhwoosh and they think there could be an issue with the plugin itself.  I will update this once I hear from them again, but it would be nice to hear if anyone had success with this.